# React native vertical timeline component

Tags: react-native

I want to create a vertical timeline(as shown below) in react native but am unable to find a decent library.Can someone suggest a library or if it's not too tricky can guide through how to accomplish without a library.

Comment: What code you have so far and how it looks like?

Comment: Why did you guys downvote this question?

Comment: @EnieJakiro Can you leave an upvote on the question if you found it useful. :)

Comment: Sure thing, helpful question / answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can implement this in a regular ListView. In each row, put a view with fixed width on the left to draw the dot and line. Inside that view, add a dot which is a view with corner radius equal to half the size (centered in both directions). Line is another view (absolute positioned). See code and screenshot below. You can wrap this into a TimeLineListView component. It will have the same interface as ListView, but content return from renderRow gets inserted into `content` view (to replace `text`).

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
} from 'react-native';

export default class timeline extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
        'row 1',
        'row 2',
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ut venenatis felis. Donec at tempus neque. Morbi vitae sem et nisi porta ornare. Cras at venenatis tellus. Curabitur consequat lacinia lacus, et luctus tortor dignissim nec. Suspendisse scelerisque aliquet vehicula. Integer at ante elit.',
        'Suspendisse potenti. Proin varius risus ac venenatis elementum. Morbi fringilla ante et nibh accumsan, ultricies tempor est porta. Nunc molestie neque a efficitur posuere. Nunc egestas, massa vitae hendrerit feugiat, ligula sem ullamcorper ante, quis ultricies quam turpis ac lectus. Praesent luctus, sapien imperdiet sagittis iaculis, nibh lacus convallis velit, sed placerat enim justo ornare tortor. Phasellus sed dui id odio lobortis imperdiet. Duis sollicitudin tellus sed eros commodo ultrices. Donec auctor nunc id quam suscipit, tempus tincidunt elit placerat. Sed nec odio vel ligula maximus varius. Nullam vulputate augue non gravida lacinia. Nam ac lobortis libero, id sollicitudin nulla.']),
    };
  }

  renderRow(rowData, section, row) {
    const total = this.state.dataSource.getRowCount();
    const topLineStyle = row == 0 ? [styles.topLine, styles.hiddenLine] : styles.topLine;
    const bottomLineStyle = row == total - 1 ? [styles.bottomLine, styles.hiddenLine] : styles.bottomLine;

    return (
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <View style={styles.timeline}>
          <View style={styles.line}>
            <View style={topLineStyle} />
            <View style={bottomLineStyle} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.dot} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <Text>{rowData}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView style={styles.listView}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  listView: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  row: {
    padding: 4,
    paddingLeft: 0,
  },
  content: {
    marginLeft: 40,
  },
  timeline: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 40,
    justifyContent: 'center', // center the dot
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  line: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 18,
    width: 4,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  topLine: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  bottomLine: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  hiddenLine: {
    width: 0,
  },
  dot: {
    width: 16,
    height: 16,
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('timeline', () => timeline);
```

[image]

Comment: This approach would probably work but I think it's a bit vague as an answer.

Comment: @HaitaoLi How to I remove top and bottom line.

Comment: I am wondering if you really need to put the datasource in the state if you won't allow the user to change the content in the timeline, and instead, you would just grab the data of the items from a remote server.