# Way to create vertical and horizontal timeline views in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, timeline, native-base

Is there a way to create vertical AND horizontal timeline views with icons in the bullets, either in React Native or preferably Native Base?

React-Native-Timeline-Listview is a start, but the bullets don't appear aligned with the text, nor does it appear possible to have a horizontal timeline.
https://github.com/thegamenicorus/react-native-timeline-listview

I also found the answer below, but find it hard to imagine nobody has developed a vertical/horizontal-flexible component already. 
[React native vertical timeline component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41844214/react-native-vertical-timeline-component)